# ¿Error en código AJAX solo emite una sola vez el código de error personalizado?

Tags: ajax

El `ajax` si me inserta los datos correctamente y si se envían los datos de igual forma.

El único problema es que solo me ejecuta una sola vez el mensaje de error.

Es decir si escribo dos veces mal la contraseña actual, el ajax me trae como respuesta que la contraseña no es valida, si vuelvo a ingresar mal nuevamente la contraseña actual el `Ajax` ya no me muestra el mensaje de error personalizado.

Tengo que volver a cargar la página para que me muestre los mensajes de error.

Me pueden explicar cual es el problema con e código `Ajax`, como solucione este error que se presente en el.

**Ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var frm = $('#resetform');
    frm.submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = frm.serialize();
        formData += '&' + $('#submit_btn').attr('name') + '=' + $('#submit_btn').attr('value');
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: formData,
            success: function(data){
                $('#message').html(data).delay(3000).fadeOut(3000);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#message').html(textStatus).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
            }

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**Formulario**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<form name="resetform" action="changepass.php" id="resetform" class="passform" method="post" role="form">
    <h3>Change Your Password</h3>
    <br />
    <label>Enter Old Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="old_password" id="old_password">
    <label>Enter New Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="new_password" id="new_password">
    <label>Confirm New Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control"  name="con_newpassword"  id="con_newpassword" />
    <br>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="password_change" id="submit_btn" value="Change Password" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas ocultando el mensaje con `fadeOut`, como por defecto esta visible, luego de la primera vuelta estará oculto, deberías mostrarlo con `fadeIn`

```
 success: function(data){
                     $('#message').fadeIn();
                    $('#message').html(data).delay(3000).fadeOut(3000);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     $('#message').fadeIn();
                    $('#message').html(textStatus).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambia la línea:

```
formData += '&' + $('#submit_btn').attr('name') + '=' + $('#submit_btn').attr('value');
```

Por:

```
formData.append($('#submit_btn').attr('name'), $('#submit_btn').attr('value'));
```